# What is the umbrella term for non-surgical, non-invasive methods in cosmetology involving the use of equipment?

Tags: terminology

I'm translating the agenda of a cosmetology training event, and one line there says:

> На одной волне: **аппаратные методы** в косметологии

In my translation:

> On the same wavelength: **hardware methods** in cosmetology

Apparently this particular presentation will be dedicated to non-invasive methods involving some "wave stumulation" of the skin.

I googled for "hardware methods in cosmetology" and the first results page seems to be filled with Russian sites translated into English, and sites from the former Soviet Union states. I thought that "hardware methods" may be a not particularly "native" term, but a calque from Russian.

Maybe there is term more commonly used by native speakers of English?

Comment: I don't think this has any relevance to medical sciences. It's simply an English usage question; therefore, I'm migrating it.

Comment: You live and learn. Cosmetology eh? And coming from the Russian I thought it had something to do with sputniks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work in a small-town hardware store selling nails over the counter. "Hardware methods" puts me in mind of door-latch testing methods, or hinge design, or perhaps in an electronic context, the physical circuits printed in silicon or on PCBs. I thought at first that you could use "instrument-assisted" or "mechanical" methods. However, the field is not particularly new, and "machine-assisted" seems to be in use already:

> Each procedure is accompanied by a presentation of the treatment’s potential and nature to ensure you have all the information you need and create a sense of trust and comfort in the ultramodern **machine-assisted** procedures. ([amberbeautyclub](https://amberbeautyclub.com/en/amber-beauty-club/))

This sentence does not make one think of invasive procedures, but there is definitely some instrumentation involved. You could also name the specific kind of machinery:

> Sonication is a reliable tool to encapsulate substances in liposomes and to emulsify them into the final product. Click here to read more about the **ultrasonically-assisted** encapsulation of liposomes! ([heilshcher.com](https://www.hielscher.com/power-ultrasound-for-the-production-of-cosmetics.htm))

Answer (score 0):

A more specific English phrase could be something like "skin treatments with devices" or "tools."

I would say the subject of an event is "device-based treatments" (focusing on treatment) or "treatment devices" (if focusing on the devices). This could need some additional description, such as "skin-treatment devices" or "hair-styling devices."

"Device" is a generic word in English; it can refer to a lot of things, as can "hardware." But a piece of "hardware" may not perform any operation, it can have little or no mechanical or electrical action. A "device" implies a piece of equipment that does something -- gives a message, exfoliates the skin, removes hair, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently this particular presentation will be dedicated to non-invasive methods involving some "wave stumulation" of the skin.

"Non-surgical cosmetic treatment/procedures" gives enough Google hits to persuade me that this is a common term, e.g.

[10 New Non-Surgical Beauty Beauty Procedures To Try In 2020](https://www.elle.com/uk/beauty/skin/a32967/6-non-surgical-beauty-procedures-you-didnt-know-about/)

[The 5 Most Popular Non-Surgical Cosmetic Procedures](https://www.saveface.co.uk/5-most-popular-non-surgical-cosmetic-procedures/)

[Nonsurgical Cosmetic Procedures for the Face - WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/beauty/ss/slideshow-non-surgical-facial-procedures)